# assign double to another double with 1 number after the decimal

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa

I want to assign the value of the double to another double, but print only 1 number after the decimal, let say i have this random **double** value and now its **23.12906370532668**

how can this be converted to only **23.1**, but stay as double value??  I could say:

```
NSLog(@"%4.1f\n", double);
```

but that is printed as string i want to assign it to another new double. From `double one =
23.12906370532668;` to `double two = 23.1;` What is the best way and how to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

am not sure about what you are trying to do, but this is probably what you want

```
double d = 23.12906370532668;
NSString *str = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%4.1f\n", d];
double d2 = [str doubleValue];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can multiply by 10, round/truncate/ceiling/floor (as you desire) to an integral value, then divide by 10.

```
double two = rint(10.0 * one) / 10.0;
```